# Оптимизация кода, генерация списков и словарей

Tags: python, list, кортежи

Вам нужно написать программу, которая принимает на вход 10 чисел и генерирует два списка. Один с четными числами, второй с нечетными.

```python
def generator(*args):
    a = list(args)

    b = [i for i in a if a[i] % 2 == 0 ]
    return b

print(generator(1, 11, 23, 432, 5432, 6543, 213, 1234, 432, 9))
```

[image: ошибка]

Comment: Исправление ошибок и оптимизация - это абсолютно разные задачи. Исправьте на `if i % 2 == 0`

Comment: Не, а ведь прикольно, что кортеж - по сути список, а словарь - список кортеджей. Ема костыли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае программа не понимает, к какому индексу вы обращаетесь, потому что списка попросту нет.

Проблема решается таким способом:

```
b = [i for i in a if i % 2 == 0 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно также использовать `filter`

```
def generator(*args):
    return [list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == i, args)) for i in range(2)]

print(generator(1, 11, 23, 432, 5432, 6543, 213, 1234, 432, 9))
```

```
[[432, 5432, 1234, 432], [1, 11, 23, 6543, 213, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Не понимаю прикола "игры в одной строке".

```
def generator(list_numbers):
    returned = {'odd':[], 'not-odd':[]}
    for n in range(len(list_numbers)):
        if list_numbers[n] % 2 == 0:
            returned['not-odd'].append(list_numbers[n])
        else:
            returned['odd'].apped(list(numbers[n]))
    return returned
```